# NetSuite Add Custom Field To Price Level

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to add fields to the price level record. The records browser states it supports them but I cannot locate which field type in the custom fields is the correct one. I have checked transaction, body, and line, item, and other but none seems to contain the choice for price level.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The records browser is not reliable in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try a 'price' field from lineitems sublist. There are two of them - price and rate. First one is total (except taxes), second - per item.

Comment: yes thanks, but in the end no one can seem to find out how to add the fields that the records browser indicates and as @brian says above sometimes the records browser is not reliable, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The records browser is not reliable in that regard